# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using JNI on ubuntu

Tags: java, java-native-interface

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using JNI.

My Testing Environment:

> Ubuntu 12.04/64-bit
>   JDK 1.7
>   gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)

This is my java source:

```
public class HelloJNI {
    static {
        //System.loadLibrary("libHelloJNI");
    }

    private native void sayHello() ;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //System.getProperties().list(System.out);
        String lib_path = System.getProperty("java.library.path");
        System.out.println("java.library.path=" + lib_path);

        System.loadLibrary("libHelloJNI");

        HelloJNI myJNI = new HelloJNI();
        myJNI.sayHello();
    }
}
```

This is my C source:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj)
{
    puts("Hello Momo. This is C code.");
    return;
}
```

This is my Makefile:

```
JNI_INC=-I"${JAVA_HOME}/include" -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux"

JNI_LIB=libHelloJNI.so
JNI_OUT=$(JNI_LIB) HelloJNI.h HelloJNI.class
CFLAGS= $(JNI_INC) -fPIC -shared

all: $(JNI_OUT)

HelloJNI.h: HelloJNI.class
    javah -jni HelloJNI

$(JNI_LIB): HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@  HelloJNI.c

HelloJNI.class: HelloJNI.java
    javac HelloJNI.java

run:
    java  HelloJNI
    #java -Djava.library.path=. HelloJNI

clean:
    rm $(JNI_OUT)
```

**When i run the java app, the OLD problem occurs:**

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
>   java.library.path=.:/home/mancook/cook/work/StSoftware/src/java/StTestJni/tutor01_HelloJNI:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib 
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libHelloJNI in java.library.path 
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886) 
>     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849) 
>     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088) 
>     at HelloJNI.main(HelloJNI.java:22) 
>   make: *** [run] Error 1

I have googled internet for this problem and find that it is an *OLD question*. But I **CANNOT** find any method to fix my problem!! Hope someone can help me. **Thanks in advance**.

Comment: Could you also paste your native file, the `HelloJNI.c`? That would make it simpler for people to reproduce this.

Comment: You need the `-Djava.library.path` to actually include the directory that contains `libHelloJNI.so`.

Comment: #include <jni.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "HelloJNI.h"


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello (JNIEnv * env, jobject thisObj)
{
 printf("Hello Momo. This is C code.");
 return;
}

Comment: Ask a non-tech question about using this website. Can i edit my question?

Comment: Yes you can edit your question. There's a grey "edit" text below your question. Everybody can edit your question. That's what StackOverflow is designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `-Djava.library.path=.` in the Makefile, and you need to load the library with **`System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");` - no `lib` prefix, no `.so` suffix**. The prefix and suffix are handled by Java - think of it, naming scheme on Windows is different (stupid but fact). And beware of the pitfall that you have `System.loadLibrary()` twice in your code, if you change only one of them, it will still fail. That one actually had cost me a few minutes :P

P.S.: I suggest a few changes to your Makefile. I would use `$(RM)` instead of `rm`. Goals which are not files should be declared `.PHONY`. Variables which do not refer to automatic variables can be assigned with `:=` instead of `=`. I would use a separate step for creating the `.so` from the `.o` file. I would use a pattern rule for compiling Java, like `%.class: %.java`. I would use a pattern rule for creating the header file, like `%.h: %.class`. The `-I` stuff should be in `CPPFLAGS` not `CFLAGS` because it's for the preprocessor. The `-shared` should then go into `LDFLAGS` and so on...

Here's your new `Makefile`:

```
CPPFLAGS:=-I"${JAVA_HOME}/include" -I"${JAVA_HOME}/include/linux"

JNI_LIB:=libHelloJNI.so
JNI_OUT:=$(JNI_LIB) HelloJNI.o HelloJNI.h HelloJNI.class
CFLAGS:=-fPIC
LDFLAGS:=-shared

.PHONY: all
all: $(JNI_OUT)

%.h: %.class
    javah -jni HelloJNI

$(JNI_LIB): HelloJNI.o
    $(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

HelloJNI.o: HelloJNI.c HelloJNI.h

%.class: %.java
    javac HelloJNI.java

.PHONY: run
run:
    java -Djava.library.path=. HelloJNI

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(JNI_OUT)
```

Comment: Thank Christian a lot for your help:) I think the reason for the failure is the the 'lib' prefix on linux

Comment: Yep it is :) And don't forget to accept the answer if you think it is correct.