# OpenMPI-java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, eclipse, native, openmpi

I want to run Open MPI from java.

I have done the following steps:

1) Downloaded OpenMPI .tar.gz from the official site

2) Created a installation directory

3) I ran
$./configure --enable-mpi-java --with-jdk-bindir="path to java bin directory " --with-jdk-headers="path to the java directroy which have jni.h" --prefix="Path to installation directory"

4)Compiled and installed OpenMPI with 
sudo make all install

5)Added the istallation direcotry/bin folder to path

6)Started eclipse and created a new project containing a MPI example I found online

7)Included the mpi.jar in the instalation directory/lib

8)Ran the program and got:

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
no mpi_java in     java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at mpi.MPI.<clinit>(MPI.java:206)
at main.Main.main(Main.java:10)`
```

I know that this means the jvm can't find the native-language definition of a native method, but have no idea how to include the native code nor where it is. 
Can someone help me get this up and running.

P.S. I have to use OpenMPI because I need it for university work.

Comment: You need to add the location of the lib (.so file) to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable before start the VM.

Comment: Can you @Konrad tell me how to do that
Which .so file?

Comment: I set the set 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/.../install directory/lib
and I still get the same excetion
@Konrad

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890188/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-when-using-jni-on-ubuntu?rq=1 seems to explain the environment.